# How to get current location in ios 8?

Tags: ios

I have been working on an ios8 program for a while, I need the source code of getting current location, if you have these please upload it in a zip file.

Comment: provide some more details?

Comment: please upload it in a zip file. Seriously???

Comment: Do you pay when the zip file is delivered or in advance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following stuff for iOS8:

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
-(void)viewDidLoad
{  
[super viewDidLoad];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] ||     [self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {
    // choose one request according to your business.
    if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    } else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
        [self.locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
    }
}
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
}
```

**You need to do two extra things to get location working:**

Add a key to your Info.plist
Request authorization from the location manager asking it to start.
Any one or both of below keys needs to be added in Info.plist file.

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
These are of String type and value can be any message description or empty.

Now you need to request authorisation for corresponding location method. Use any one of below calls :

`[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`
`[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`